# What does "looking like a zygote" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idioms, idiomatic-language

In [this review of *The Wheel of Time* tv series](https://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2021/nov/19/the-wheel-of-time-review-amazon-robert-jordan), the reviewer, Lucy Mangan, writes:

> There is also Nynaeve (Zoë Robins) – a Wisdom who, despite looking like a zygote, seems to be a protective village elder.

Googling on it, I don't get a lot of hits except for the literal explanation of what a zygote is. What does "looking like a zygote" mean in this context? Is it a common idiom?

Comment: No, it's not a common idiom. The review makes several attempts at humorous comments about the appearance of the cast members: most are not very funny, and I don't get this one at all. Maybe the reviewer had been smoking something illegal when she wrote this.

Comment: @JavaLatte - common enough. A random selection - Looking back on the film [_Titanic_] now,  Leonardo DiCaprio is practically a zygote with his boyish good looks, and Winslet’s acting skills have clearly improved over time. Also - my jealousy in Zadie Smith for being published so young, practically a zygote.

Answer (score 1):

When a daddy and a mommy like each other very, *very* much... one of the mommy's ova and one of the daddy's sperms may fuse together to create a new being. This very first cell is called a zygote. The zygote then starts to divide, and over time a litte baby is created.

So, the zygote is the very first stage we've all been in - you may say, the youngest version of us possible. In the phrase you've quoted, the author probably wants to express that the character is looking *really* young. They do that by the means of hyperbole, by comparing her to the youngest possible stage in an individual's life.

Comment: The OP says that they _know_ the literal meaning!

Comment: @KateBunting And my answer explains how the author of the quote probably used the literal meaning to express that the character looks very, very young.

Comment: "When a daddy and a mommy like each other very, very much" - is this an essential condition?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey At least it should be, otherwise there's a chance they'll take it out on their offspring later. But I mostly wanted to quote one of the cliché phrases often used in this context. I thought about bringing the stork into play, but decided against it ;)

Comment: Parents in the UK used to tell their children 'We found you under a gooseberry bush'.